# Matlab ordfilt2 or alternatives for weighted local max

Tags: matlab, max, morphological-analysis

I would like to compute the weighted maxima of a vector in Matlab. For weighted maxima I intend the following:

Given a vector of `2*N+1` weights `W={w[-N], w[-N+1] .. w[0] .. w[N]}` and given an input sequence `A`,  weighted maxima is a vector  `M` where  `m[i]=max(w[-N]*a[i-N], w[-N+1]*a[i-N+1], ... w[N]*a[i+N])`

So for example given a vector `A= [1, 4, 12, 2, 4]` and weights `W=[0.5, 1, 0.5]`, the weighted maxima would be `M=[2, 6, 12, 6, 4]`.

This can be done using `ordfilt2`, but `ordfilt2` uses weights as additive rather then multiplicative.

I am actually working on 4D matrixes, but any 1D solution would work as the 4D weight matrix is separable.

My current solution is to generate shifted copies of the input array `A`, weight them according to the shift and maximize all the arrays. Shift is performed using `circshift` and is the bottleneck in the process. generating shifted matrixes "manually" trough indexing turned out to be even slower.

Can you suggest any more efficient solution?

EDIT: For a positive A, `M=exp(ordfilt2(log(A), length(W), ones(size(W)), log(W)))`  does the job, but still takes longer than the `circshift` solution above. I am still looking for more efficient solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> B = padarray(A, [0 floor(numel(W)/2)], 0); % Pad A with zeros
>> B = bsxfun(@times, B(bsxfun(@plus, 1:numel(B)-numel(W)+1, (0:numel(W)-1)')), W(:)); % Apply the weights
>> M = max(B)  % Compute the local maxima
M =
     2     6    12     6     4
```

Comment: This may or may not be more efficient than ordfilt2! Time it on your actual problem and see.